# Integre Jquery in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have integre Jquery in Typescript but I have this error:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryStatic'.

config.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "pretty": true,
        "experimentalDecorators":true
    },

    "files": [
        "demo.ts",
        "typings/index.d.ts"
    ],

    "excluse": ["node_modules"]
}
```

demo.ts:

```
declare var $: JQueryStatic;

$('.test').click(function(eventObject){
    alert('hello');
})
```

and this is screen of my project:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xa9rk.png)

Comment: It sounds like the typescript compilation is not including the .d.ts file for jquery; not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

> I have integre Jquery in Typescript but I have this error:

Just use `@types`. Run: `npm install @types/jquery -D`.

## More

https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/migrating.html